# How to fix "bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigging, bones

i have rigged this gingerbread man, and also i have made everything one object so when i rig it, the **WHOLE** gingerbread man will move. but when i parent it, it says " bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones". how can i fix this?

[image]

here is the blend file:

[image]

EDIT: after trying to figure out the problem, i discovered this problem only occurs when i set the parent with automatic weights. hope that helps.

Comment: If this model isn't going to be super close to the camera I would recommend making the frosting an texture on the body. An alternative could be to use a cage mesh and a mesh deform modifier to make sure the frosting stays on the body as having it be a separate object and using standard armature parenting will likely make it clip through the body at points.

Comment: how can i make it a texture?

Comment: Could it be that your frostings are curves? If so, try to convert them to meshes. (ALT+C) Then you should be able to join them. But they wont start following your armature by just joining the geometry

Comment: they are curves, and i converted all of them to meshes. still wont work

Comment: So it will still give you an error?

Comment: yes. before i even added the armature, i made it a mesh. :)

Comment: Hmm that is Strange. You first selected the frosting and then you selected the mainbody? And then ctrl +j?

Comment: i didn't make it one object, if you re-read my post, i don't want to make it one object. i can, but when i parent the whole thing to the armature, it gives me an error message saying " Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" and if you want exactly what i did: selected the gingerbread man, selected the armature, tapped "CTRL, P" and then clicked on "with automatic weights"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the frosting move according to the main body I would recommend the DataTransfer modifier as solution.

Therefore you should parent the frosting to the same armature as the Gingerbread man. But you don't have to make weights just the empty vertex groups.

My example scene looks like this

[image: Setup]

So, for Bone deformation we need the Vertexgroup information projected from the Base(your gngerbread man) to the Addon(your frosting).

The modifier has to be on the Addon and it should look like this.

[image: ModifierProperties]

depending to the Size of your object you may change the ray radius

After getting the weight information from the base object you should be able to join the two meshes together(but you don't have to). The frosting should have reasonable weighting.

EDIT:

**After projecting the vertexgroups you have to apply the DataTransfer modifier, because it will automatically recalculate it when you change your pose.**

Edit2:

**Parent just one object at the same time to the armature.**

[image]

Comment: so i add this modifier to the gingerbread man or the frosting?

Comment: to the frosting but you can look up everything in the .blendfile

Comment: is there any easier way? i think maybe adding a texture as the frosting is the way to go. i just don't know which texture/how to apply that.

Comment: i think i will redo the rigging, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: redid the rigging, still didn;t work. tried your method and it works, but its super laggy because i had to ctrl-j the frosting with the gingerbread man. the frosting has quite a lot of vertices, so how can i go about removing them, because now my vertice count is 3 million.

Comment: putting the blend file in the post

Comment: You already gasped the problem you have. I would recommend to reduce your polycount. For features in this size I would give it a maximal polycount of 10000. And even this is a lot. 3 mil for the frosting is a total overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the automatic parenting is failing is because it has a hard time with very dense, overlapping meshes.

The solution is to either make the frosting meshes much less dense or finding another way to put the frosting on the gingerbread man.

One way to put frosting on your gingerbread man is to paint it on using texture paint. I gave it a quick try and it seems to work quite well. I used the Lightmap Pack UV unwrap option, then went to texture paint mode and added a paint slot. The head of your character does appear to have double vertices which will need to be removed before painting though. After that just select the base color and use the fill tool to color the base, then choose the frosting color and paint it on. It will take some practice if you're new to texture painting, but it's definitely a possible way to go about adding the frosting.

As far as reducing the amount of vertices if you want to keep the frosting as a mesh object, I would suggest starting with a cube, scaling it down to the width of the frosting, selecting a side face and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Click to extrude the face and create the shape. Then add a subsurf modifier at the end to make is smoother. Currently the mesh is just too dense to simplify effectively, and you would spend more time working with the frosting objects you have than if you make new ones.